# Creating a URL object to read data of webpage and send OTP in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

```
Random otp = new Random();
d1 = otp.nextInt(10);
d2 = otp.nextInt(10);
d3 = otp.nextInt(10);
d4 = otp.nextInt(10);
String smsOTP = d1+""+d2+d3+d4;
URL myurl = new URL("http://someURL/"+smsOTP);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myurl.openStream()));
String output="";
String inputLine;
while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    output = inputLine;
}
out.println(output);
in.close();
```

This code is working perfectly in Java, but due to some reasons, I have to put it in a JavaScript function. But I am not able to open the link correctly. It doesn't give any error, but it also doesn't execute the function at all. I have been able to convert it this far. I am not sure how to create a URL object and read data from that URL.

```
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var d3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var d4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var smsOTP = ""+d1+d2+d3+d4;
    alert(smsOTP);
    URL myurl = new URL("http://2factor.in/API/V1/api-key/SMS/phoneNumber/"+smsOTP);
    BufferedReader bufread=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myurl.openStream()));
    var output="";
    var inputLine;
    while((inputLine = bufread.readLine()) != null)
    {
        output = inputLine;
    }
    console.log(output);
    bufread.close();
```

Comment: SO is not a translation service. JavaScript may not be able to help you here unless the URL supports CORS. If it does, you can use Ajax

Comment: That URL is an API endpoint, I load the url and and sms OTP is sent to the mentioned number. Will that work? In the java code, I am just trying to read the data on url. Can similar be done in JavaScript?

Comment: My comment still applies. If the endpoint supports CORS and allows your Ajaxing to it, then possibly. If not, no way unless you go via a server proxy

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried writing so far? What errors do you get? What does it do? Please update your answer with these things.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan! Will see to it.

Comment: @samanime, I have mostly converted the code line by line. I am stuck at creating the URL object and then passing it to BufferedReader to read it's data. What that code basically does that is when the url is opened, it sends an OTP code and a response msg is printed on the webpage which is read by BufferedReader and outputted on the screen.

Comment: I'm familiar with what your Java code does. What we'd like to see is the JS code you've written so far so we can help spot your issue. As mplungjan mentioned, we aren't here to just translate code for you. We're here to help fix small issues in code you've written.

Comment: @samanime. Get a look now, I have added my javascript code.